# Getting <ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 2> when running text_from_bytes function below with multiple bytes as input

Tags: python

The function should get the string equivalent of any number of bytes and print that result. When I input one byte, the code returns the string value. When I input multiple bytes as shown below, the ValueError occurs. How can I modify the function to allow multiple bytes?

```
def text_from_bytes(bytes, encoding='utf-8', errors='surrogatepass'):
  n = int(bytes, 2)
  print(n.to_bytes((n.bit_length() + 7) // 8, 'big').decode(encoding, 
  errors) or '\0')

convert = "01000001 01000010"
text_from_bytes(convert)
```

Comment: What do you expect as the result for this example?

Answer (score 1):

`int` does not know how to parse a string that contains a space. Try filtering the space out before calling int.

```
def text_from_bytes(bytes, encoding='utf-8', errors='surrogatepass'):
  n = int(bytes.replace(" ", ""), 2)
  print(n.to_bytes((n.bit_length() + 7) // 8, 'big').decode(encoding, 
  errors) or '\0')

convert = "01000001 01000010"
text_from_bytes(convert)
```

Result:

```
AB
```